Bot created for buy and sell transactions on Solana chain (cryptocurrency) but getting error
Error on the bot when it tries to buy/sell =>"The first argument must be of type string or an instance of buffer, Arraybuffer, or array or an array-like object"
Tried to establsih if there is an API connection problem, but not exists
